# How to import in R variables that contain lists created in Python?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a `csv` that contains a variable that appears as follows (after I read it in R using `fread` followed by `as_tibble`):

```
 myvar
 <chr>
 []
 [u'welcome']
 [u'the oil price']
```

The variable has been created in `Python`, and I have to deal with this pythonesque list.

Is there a way using the `tidyverse` (`dplyr` and others) to actually read-in this variable directly as a proper string (and not a list) without filtering myself all the `[`, `]`] and `u'` ?

```
 myvar_wanted
 <chr>
  NA
 'welcome'
 'the oil price'
```

Thanks!

Comment: `gsub('\'(.*)\'|.', '\\1', data$myvar)` maybe?

Comment: nice one, can you put that as an answer? I guess there has to be some manual filtering in any case

Comment: @rawr that works perfectly but I dont understand your regex. Can you please elaborate just a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings won't contain any single quotes, you can use `'\\[u\'(.*)\'\\]'` which matches a bracket followed by "u" and the text surrounded by single quotes ended with another bracket. Then you can extract what was between the single quotes by capturing it (this is `myvar3` below)

Easier (to me) is to capture exactly what you want and ignore the rest, so `\'(.*)\'|.` will match a single quote, capture any character any number of times to group `\1` up to another single quote. The `|.` allows us not to write out the exact pattern as we did in `myvar3`.

```
data <- data.frame(myvar = c("[]", "[u'welcome']", "[u'the oil price']"))

within(data, {
  myvar2 <- gsub('\'(.*)\'|.', '\\1', myvar)
  myvar3 <- gsub('\\[(?:u\'(.*)\')?\\]', '\\1', myvar)
})


#                myvar        myvar3        myvar2
# 1                 []                           
# 2       [u'welcome']       welcome       welcome
# 3 [u'the oil price'] the oil price the oil price
```

Comment: @Noobie sorry updated the second regex since the u and quotes are optional, now they match exactly